# Monthly subscription with Stripe using iDEAL

Tags: stripe

Does anybody know if I can use Stripe to facilitate subscription payments using iDEAL (Dutch payment method). For instance using the Charge plugin or Sprout Commerce? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried having a look at the API Docs for Stripe? They have written about ideal integration:

https://stripe.com/docs/sources/ideal

If its in your budget you should probably also have a look at Craft commerce which has partial Mollie integration which should, in turn, facilitate the iDeal payments solution that you are looking for. Though they do say it is only partially supported so you may need to investigate if this is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi, I already used Commerce before, but it is too big/expensive for a simple payment feature I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

[Stripe Payments](https://enupal.com/craft-plugins/stripe-payments) is available in the plugin store for Craft CMS 3. We just added support to iDEAL for one-time and recurring payments.

Best,